# How to set IntField from native jni to Java Android 10

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-10.0

After update my project to support Android 10, a crash produced in the JNI level related to non-SDK interface restrictions in Android 10 :

```
 JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI SetIntField called with pending exception java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no "I" field "value" in class "Ljava/lang/Integer;" or its superclasses
```

which come from this part of code :

```
jclass clazz = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, outputObj);
jfieldID mi = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, clazz, "value", "I");
(*env)->SetIntField(env, outputObj, mi, pListLen);
```

To fix that i replace it by :

```
jclass clazz = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, outputObj);
jmethodID intValueMethod = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, clazz, "intValue", "()I");
jint result = (*env)->CallIntMethod(env, outputObj,intValueMethod,pListLen);
```

After that my application doesn't crash and find the integer value correctly, but i want to set the result integer on Java code using the same method SetIntField.

Could you please give me a way or method to set the result on the Java part.

Comment: You're not supposed to change the internal value of `Integer` objects, that breaks all kinds of invariants! Please explain why you think you need to do this; maybe we can find another way.

Comment: Thank you for your response, the outputObj will be used later in the java part but before the update of Android 10 the SetIntField make the work perfectly, so i want  if there is an alternative method to set my outputObj to return it to java part

Comment: Use the `Integer#valueOf(int)` overload to construct a new `Integer` object instead.

Comment: _"before the update of Android 10 the SetIntField make the work perfectly"_ The fact that was working before sounds like a bug to me. `Integer`s are supposed to be immutable, since e.g. the same `Integer` instance may be reused if you do `Integer.valueOf` multiple times for values < 128.

Comment: @Botje i have tried your code but the outputObj doesn't change. Here is what i want to do: i want to  set outputObj by this value     size_t pListLen = (size_t)(*env)->GetArrayLength(env, List);
And on this part i set the value to java part :      jclass clazz = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, outputCidpuBufLen);
    jmethodID valueOfMethod = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env,clazz, "valueOf", "(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;");
    (*env)->CallStaticObjectMethod(env,clazz, valueOfMethod, (jint)pListLen); and finally on the java part the new value does'nt appear , it's really strange behavior

Comment: None of my suggestions alter an existing object. I explicitly told you that you are not allowed to change the internal value of an Integer object. Stop trying.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As changing the intger field is not a good practice on JNI part, so i changed the way instead changing it by reflection method

```
    jclass clazz = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, outputBufLen);
    jmethodID value_of = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env,clazz, "valueOf", "(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;");
    jobject result = (*env)->CallStaticObjectMethod(env,clazz, value_of, pOutBufLen);
```

I set the result under an int Array and i return it :

```
int result = (*env)->CallStaticObjectMethod(env,clazz, value_of, pOutBufLen);

jintArray resultArray = (*env)->NewIntArray(env, 2);
jint fill[2];
fill[0] = result;
fill[1] = (jint) pOutBufLen;
(*env)->SetIntArrayRegion(env, result, 0, 2, fill);

return (resultArray);
```

Comment: As i need to return two result :

Comment: To whom? You never showed the calling code and you never explained why you were trying to change the internal value of an Integer. Please edit your question to include the calling code and maybe then we can formulate an answer for you.

Comment: Sorry for not to be clear about my needs : as i need to return two values : first one return the result of internal method  ` int ret = tlcGetCidpuList(virtualTabKey, virtualTabKeyLen, &param_t, pList , &pListLen); `

Comment: and the second value which i must returned also is `pOutBufLen`  so finally instead return an integer and set the other one by a refelction method    ` jclass clazz = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, outputBufLen);
    jmethodID value_of = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env,clazz, "valueOf", "(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;");
    jobject result = (*env)->CallStaticObjectMethod(env,clazz, value_of, pOutBufLen); `  i changed the way to return two integer and managed it on java part  ( please be polite in the comments !) ;)

Comment: Please **edit your question** with the calling code and **requirements** or ask a new question.

Comment: Note to future readers: this answer puts the **address** of a `java.lang.Integer` object as the first element of this `int` array. Use at your own risk.