# Java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no “I” field “value” in class “Ljava/lang/Integer;” or its superclasses

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I have the following code in one of the native Android libraries that I am using

```
static void setInteger(JNIEnv* env, int val, jobject integer)
{
    auto clazz = env->FindClass("java/lang/Integer");
    if (clazz == nullptr)
        return;

    auto id = env->GetFieldID(clazz, "value", "I");
    if (id == nullptr)
        return;

    env->SetIntField(integer, id, val);
}
```

However, the code crashes with the following error.

> --- End of managed Java.Lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError stack trace --- java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no "I" field "value" in class "Ljava/lang/Integer;" or its superclasses at
> com.esong.lib.EPM002Lib.ReadParams(Native Method)

I am new to JNI and was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction?

Thanks much

Comment: Is there a reason people want to [change immutable Integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59733790/how-to-set-intfield-from-native-jni-to-java-android-10) with native code on Android? Why would you write such code?

Comment: The code was given to me by a 3rd party, I am just trying to fix a problem.

Comment: That function can't be used, so you'll probably have to rewrite the code that uses `setInteger` to do something else instead. Since we don't know how you're currently using `setInteger` we can't say what that "something else" should be.